# Getting accurate Julian date number for current time in Ruby

Tags: ruby, date, time, julian-date

`Date.today.jd` returns a rounded number.  Is there a way to get more precision in Ruby?

I want to return a Julian date for the current time in UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Date#amjd`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-amjd) method does what you're asking for, but it returns a Rational; converting to a Float gives you something easier to work with:

```
require 'date'

DateTime.now.amjd.to_f # => 56759.82092321331
```

Comment: @ArupRakshit No, the `ajd` method is similar but doesn't, I think, do what the questioner is asking for.  That said, if I'd seen your answer before starting mine, I probably would have just commented on yours suggesting the `amjd` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
require "date"
p jdate = DateTime.now.julian #=> #<DateTime: 2014-03-30T21:28:30+02:00 (...)
p jdate.julian?               # => true
```